# LocalSocket write and flush ends in broken pipe error

Tags: java, android, sockets, google-chrome-devtools, unix-socket

I'm trying to communicate with Chrome's developer tools using their socket's protocol inside Android. 
The USB debugging option in chrome is enabled, and if I do a adb forward from my computer, I am able to interact with the socket. But I need to access it programatically inside the phone.

Here's some code:

```
package something;

import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.net.LocalServerSocket;
import android.net.LocalSocket;
import android.net.LocalSocketAddress;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

public class SomeService extends Service {
    private final String TAG = SomeService.class.toString();
    private int cnt = 0;
    public static String SOCKET_ADDRESS = "chrome_devtools_remote";
    private String message = "/json";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "service started");
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run()
             {
                try {
                    LocalSocket receiver = new LocalSocket(LocalSocket.SOCKET_STREAM);
                    receiver.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(SOCKET_ADDRESS, LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.ABSTRACT));
                    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder().append("GET /json HTTP/1.0\r\n");
                    BufferedOutputStream outbuf = new BufferedOutputStream(receiver.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedInputStream inbuf = new BufferedInputStream(receiver.getInputStream());
                    byte[] buffer = request.toString().getBytes("utf-8");    
                    Log.d(TAG, "outbuf size " + Integer.toString(receiver.getSendBufferSize()));
                    while (true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "sending " + request.toString());
                        outbuf.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        outbuf.flush();
                        Log.d(TAG, "sent!");
                        byte[] output = new byte[1000];
                        int read = inbuf.read();
                        int size = 0;
                        int capacity = 0;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[capacity];

                        // reading
                        while (read != -1) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "recieving");
                            capacity = (capacity * 3)/2 + 1;
                            byte[] copy = new byte[capacity];
                            System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, copy, 0, bytes.length);
                            bytes = copy;
                            bytes[size++] = (byte)read;

                            // read next byte
                            read = inbuf.read();
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, new String(bytes));
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);    
                        } catch(Exception e) {

                        }

                    }                 

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(),e);
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

This always results in this error:

```
Starting service: Intent { cmp=something/.MyService (has extras) }
D/class something.MyService(18717): service started
D/class something.MyService(18717): outbuf size 163840
D/class something.MyService(18717): sending GET /json HTTP/1.0
E/something.MyService$1(18717): Broken pipe
E/something.MyService$1(18717): java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
E/something.MyService$1(18717):  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.writeba_native(Native Method)
E/something.MyService$1(18717):  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$600(LocalSocketImpl.java:33)
E/something.MyService$1(18717):  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream.write(LocalSocketImpl.java:134)
E/something.MyService$1(18717):  at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
E/something.MyService$1(18717):  at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85)
E/something.MyService$1(18717):  at something.MyService$1.run(RTCService.java:49)
E/something.MyService$1(18717):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The socket is definitely open, which I am checking using `isConnected()` method of the socket object. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The peer has closed the connection. Why are you implementing HTTP yourself instead of using the facilities provided?

Comment: Hey Munim, I am facing similar problem. Did you get to solve this?

Comment: @mdasari I just ended up reading it from an external api source which had more data along with this data which it was collecting using an adb forwarded port. I think I may be able to fix this today after 3 years, but don't need to revisit this!

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue, it seems that you're not calling setSendBufferSize/setReceiveBufferSize on your receiver object, after doing this I got further with my problem, though it is NOT yet an entire solution for me.

<strike>I am trying to send to my own native abstract socket and so far it seems that the write is being done 1 byte at a time, and since I am calling recv just once on my "server" side, the pipe is broken after the 1st byte.</strike>

in other words, I am expecting send("HELLO"), but the Java stream implementation seems to be doing send("H"),send("E"),send("L"),send("L"),send("O").

EDIT:

If it helps, here is the code that did end working for me:

```
LocalSocket socket = new LocalSocket ( LocalSocket.SOCKET_STREAM );
socket.connect ( new LocalSocketAddress ( "someaddress" ) );
if ( socket.isConnected() )
{
     socket.setSendBufferSize ( 128 );
     OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
     out.write ( ... );
     socket.close();
     socket = null;
}
```

EDIT:

After reading comments on my answer, I think the problem in the OP is that the request should be:

```
StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder().append("GET /json HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
```

since the empty line marks the end of request headers and the start of the server's data transmit.

Comment: Buffer sizes don't have much to do with connection resets, and this is not an answer to the question. TCP can segment and IP can fragment the TCP data stream any way it likes: that has nothing to do with connection resets either.

Comment: You're right, I solved my problem and it had nothing to do with buffer sizes.

Comment: To the OP, If you're still looking for clues make sure you're posting/sending/writing exactly what the socket expects, you can use "adb forward tcp:<unused port on the host> localabstract:<unix domain socket on the target>" to connect  with telnet to the localhost:port and send your GET string and see what exactly is going on with the connection... by the way, the \r\n at the end of your GET is suspicious, first, the \r is windows only, and IIRC, http expects 2 new lines as end of input, so change it to \n\n.

Comment: @RodrigoHernandez, I tried with telnet. It is working at telnet. That is, I am receiving the JSON objects. But, when I try the same in the app, I am not receiving anything. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @mdasari Sorry, it's been a while, I had to try different kinds of RPCs until I got something working and TBH, I am not sure if the success I was speaking about above is the same that ended up in my final code. I avandoned the project I was working on as it required a rooted phone. I'll add the piece of code as an answer in case it helps.

Comment: @RodrigoHernandez Thanks for your reply and sample code. I am using same code to connect to chrome but somehow unable to send or receive messages from chrome. My phone is rooted though. Anyway thanks for the insight, I will try to debug.

Comment: @RodrigoHernandez The OP's line termination is correct. The line terminator in HTTP is defined as `\r\n`. There should be two of them, i.e. a terminator and a blank line, at the end of the headers. `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. 128 is far too small for a socket send buffer, and will be enlarged by the platform to its minimum, which will be more like 4096. Your theory that Java sends one byte at a time is certainly false as well.

Comment: @EJP I see, in my case I was not trying to connect to an http server, just a simple socket, as I mentioned, for RPC. 128 was more than enough for me as I was sending just a handful of floats.

My recv side was JNI, so it was standard c socket code.

Anyway, just a though: if the line terminator is \r\n, then the correct message should had ended with \r\n\r\n as the double line break or rather the empty line is what marks the end of the request headers, that may have been the issue here.